# email attachment not opening after ISO8 upgrade

Tags: ios

I have have a app working great in ISO7 which has a Public.filename-extension in the info.plist to associate sqlite files, a week ago I could email a sqlite file to the users of the app, they could select the file use the "open in" option to update the app data. Since the upgrade to ISO8 the sqlite file is still associated and give the "Open in" option but when selected it fires up the app, but the data is not updated anymore, anyone else had this problem ?

Comment: - (void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {databaseName = @"KpiDB5.sqlite";
NSData *dbFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];NSString *filePathx = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];[dbFile writeToFile:filePathx atomically:YES];[self refresh];}

Comment: Im trying to understand where the problem may be, the code overwrites the Sqlite bundled file, has the bundle path changed in ISO8?

Comment: Your first issue here is that you haven't shared your code (Don't just say it's in the comments) so no one would have been able to help you at all.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, however I added the code as a comment, is this not visible to you?

Comment: No it is perfectly visible but that's not how this works. If you have code to share that is relevant to your question you need to edit your question to include it. No one will look at code that isn't formatted in a comment. There is an edit but located under your question use that to add your code and also follow the instructions on how to format your code correctly because I had to reformat you code in you answer.

Comment: read your comment & will work to get it right for next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by not saving to the NSBundle mainBundle

```
- (void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{

    NSData *dbFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];

    NSError *writeError = nil;


    NSString *filePathx = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [dbFile writeToFile:filePathx atomically:YES];

    if (writeError) {
       NSLog(@"Error writing file: %@", writeError);
    }

    [self refresh];
}
```

Comment: Bit of code reviewing here. Why do you have a redundant line of `databaseName = @"KpiDB5.sqlite";` when you could pass it directly like `[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"KpiDB5.sqlite"];`? You never use `databaseName` again in this method, I'm also going to question why you have it as a property/ivar and not a local variable? Do you use this again else where in your code?

Comment: Thank you for the spot, when I changed the code, I missed removing this piece of code, also yes it is referenced in other areas of the code

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect your comment, many thanks for looking